# How to get a specific time window in SQL for the past 12 Months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a way to get a certain time window of the past 12 Months from current date.

I want to get every day from the past 12 Months but there is a specific time window in between those dates because there is a start date and an end date.

So one day would be.

```
SELECT startdate, enddate
     FROM TableX
      WHERE 
         startdate >= SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()-1), 05, 00) 
     AND enddate <= SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), 05, 00)
```

That would give me yesterdays date "2021-11-14T05:00:00Z" to todays date ("2021-11-15T05:00:00Z") .
Now I want this for the past 12 Months. Between yesterdays date an todays date are different timestamps that come with a specific value.

So I need to sum up every value in beetween that timestamp.

Comment: Why can't you just `DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())`?

Comment: I edited the question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I still don't see why you can't use what @SalmanA suggested. If you want 12 month's wroth of data, why do you want to do it day by day, and not just write a statement that effective asks "I want the last 12 month's"?

Comment: Are you trying to exclude rows of any date that have a time portion before 5:00 am? You can't do that with a single boundary condition? Nor will that work with the upper boundary at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using the EOMONTH function you can also calculate the start of the month for a given date.

So this

```
select 
 CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,-12,DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))) AS SMALLDATETIME) AS startDate, 
 CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)) AS SMALLDATETIME) AS endDate
```

Returns this (when run today, November 2021)

| startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-01 00:00 | 2021-11-01 00:00 |

The query for the previous 12 months :

```
SELECT startdate, enddate
FROM TableX
WHERE startdate >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,-12,DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))) AS SMALLDATETIME)
  AND enddate < CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)) AS SMALLDATETIME)
```